# Происхождение фразеологизма

Tags: фразеология

А интересует меня поговорка "Вот где собака зарыта". Откуда она пошла?

Answer (score 2):

С уверенностью могу сказать, что в русском появилось как каклька с немецкого "Da liegt der Hund begraben" (Da ist der Hund begraben). Такие совпадения случайными не бывают. Но очень сомнительно, что происхождение связано с исторяими о королях, воинах и кладоискателях. Скорее всего это просто идиома "сути дела", наподобие "мысли", якобы  растекающейся по древу.
Впрочем, приведу ещё одну версию, ранее слышанную, но почему-то не найденную в интернете. Древние германцы якобы зарывали собак в особых святых местах. Или наоборот, места таких захоронений считали святыми, не помню уж сейчас. Версия не более достоверна, чем все предыдущие, но она по крайней мере проверяема.

Comment: Да, о кальке с немецкого я тоже читала. Всё это очень интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот где собака зарыта!

Существует рассказ: австрийский воин Сигизмунд Альтенштейг все походы и битвы провел вместе со своей любимой собакой. А однажды, во время путешествия по Нидерландам, собака ценой своей жизни спасла от гибели хозяина. Благодарный воин торжественно похоронил своего четвероногого друга и на его могиле поставил памятник, простоявший более двух столетий – до начала XIX века.

Позже собачий памятник мог быть разыскан туристами лишь при помощи местных жителей. В то время и родилась поговорка «Вот где собака зарыта!», имеющая ныне смысл: «нашел, что искал», «докопался до сути».

Но есть более древний и не менее вероятный источник дошедшей до нас поговорки. Когда греки решили дать персидскому царю Ксерксу сражение на море, они заранее посадили на суда стариков, женщин и детей и переправили их на остров Саламин.

Рассказывают, что собака, принадлежавшая Ксантиппу, отцу Перикла, не пожелала расстаться со своим хозяином, прыгнула в море и вплавь, вслед за судном, добралась до Саламина. Изнемогшая от усталости, она тут же издохла.

По свидетельству историка древности Плутарха, этой собаке поставили на берегу острова Киносему  собачий памятник, который очень долго показывали любопытным.

Некоторые немецкие лингвисты полагают, что это выражение создано кладоискателями, которые из суеверного страха перед нечистой силой, якобы сторожащей каждый клад, не решались прямо упоминать о цели своих поисков и условно стали говорить о «черном псе» и собаке, подразумевая под этим черта и клад.

Таким образом, согласно этой версии, выражение «Вот где собака зарыта», означало: «Вот где клад зарыт».(http://www.otrezal.ru/catch-words/64.html)